# Appmaker Unexpected client error. EditorLauncher SEVERE: Unexpected error

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm having a problem on appmaker, I can't seem to open load appmaker and by extension, cant load my projects.

What I already tried:

- accessing 2 different projects with two different accounts of the same domain ( one is the owner of the two projects and the owner a normal dev account with given access )
- opening appmaker from chrome incognito window and other browsers
- opening appmaker using an account from another domain the the first two

All these attempts always give me the same error which is:
 `com.google.apps.appmaker.client.editor.EditorLauncher
SEVERE: Unexpected error
com.google.apps.appmaker.shared.property.binding.BindingException: Unexpected error on binding initial sync write`

I added a some screenshots to show the error. I really dont know whats up, any hints or help would be appreciated !

thanks !

[image][image]

Comment: The issue was caused by a release. Appmaker team did a rollback and I have access to the projects now. :)